# Windows Server 2003 Server to Server proxy avoidance configuration

Tags: windows, web-services, proxy, iis-6

Is it possible to configure Windows Servers that reside on the same domain such that when a web service call is made from a web app using an IP address, the request does not go via a proxy server?

The web service is running on one of the servers on the domain.

I want to configure IP based security on the server that hosts the web service such that it only allows connections from specific servers.  Currently all requests go via the proxy server rendering IPSec problematic.

Within the browser I can specify that requests following a specific pattern should bypass the proxy server.  It's essentially this behaviour I want to replicate with the servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxycfg looked promising, however the following code was what I needed to do it programmatically:-

```
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0") 

xmlhttp.SetProxy 2,"proxyname:port", "addresses that should bypass the proxy"
```

this allowed me to specify the addresses that should bypass the specified proxy and it works great now

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think that proxycfg.exe has what you need. Its a console application that is part of standard windows installation.
look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384069.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With ASMX the proxy can be set on the Proxy property:

http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!435.entry

With WCF, this is part of the binding configuration:

http://blogs.infosupport.com/porint/archive/2007/08/14/Configuring-a-proxy_2D00_server-for-WCF.aspx